# How to get Image extension/format from UIImage in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, nsdata

I am trying to upload an image to my server, but before uploading, i need to check whether it is valid format or not.

let say i only want `.jpeg` and `.png` only, so if the users pick `.gif` format image from their phone, I will show some alert.

I get the image from the user gallery/camera, and then I want to check the format, but I don't know how to check the format

```
@IBAction func selectPictureButtonDidPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
    
    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Photo Source", message: "please choose your source", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    
    // action camera
    let actionCamera = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default) { (action) in
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera
            self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            self.showAlert(alertTitle: "Opppss", alertMessage: "camera can't be used / not available", actionTitle: "OK")
            print("camera can't be used / not available")
        }
    }
    
    // action photo library
    let actionPhotoLibrary = UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .default) { (action) in
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    //action cancel
    let actionCancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    
    actionSheet.addAction(actionCamera)
    actionSheet.addAction(actionPhotoLibrary)
    actionSheet.addAction(actionCancel)
    
    self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    postImage.image = image
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    
    doesItHasImage = true
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

How do I check that format?

i have tried to find on google, but I just get the image format if it is derived from an URL. not directly from UIImage like this

```
import UIKit
import ImageIO

struct ImageHeaderData{
    static var PNG: [UInt8] = [0x89]
    static var JPEG: [UInt8] = [0xFF]
    static var GIF: [UInt8] = [0x47]
    static var TIFF_01: [UInt8] = [0x49]
    static var TIFF_02: [UInt8] = [0x4D]
}

enum ImageFormat{
    case Unknown, PNG, JPEG, GIF, TIFF
}

extension NSData{
    var imageFormat: ImageFormat{
        var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 1)
        self.getBytes(&buffer, range: NSRange(location: 0,length: 1))
        if buffer == ImageHeaderData.PNG
        {
            return .PNG
        } else if buffer == ImageHeaderData.JPEG
        {
            return .JPEG
        } else if buffer == ImageHeaderData.GIF
        {
            return .GIF
        } else if buffer == ImageHeaderData.TIFF_01 || buffer == ImageHeaderData.TIFF_02{
            return .TIFF
        } else{
            return .Unknown
        }
    }
}

// USAGE
let imageURLFromParse = NSURL(string : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/R64uj.jpg")
let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: imageURLFromParse! as URL)
print(imageData!.imageFormat)
```

Comment: Unrelated by there's no point to using `NSURL` and then casting it to `URL`. Just use `URL` to begin with. And same for `NSData`. Just use `Data`.

Comment: The code you posted shows no attempt to determine the image type from a `UIImage` (which doesn't have a type).

Comment: so if we can't check file extension from UIImage, is there any alternative to check image format ?

Comment: `UIImage` has no format unless you create `Data` from the `UIImage` using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation`. But then you already know the format of that data since you just chose a specific format.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try this:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    let assetPath = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
    if (assetPath.absoluteString?.hasSuffix("JPG"))! {
        print("JPG")
    }
    else if (assetPath.absoluteString?.hasSuffix("PNG"))! {
        print("PNG")
    }
    else if (assetPath.absoluteString?.hasSuffix("GIF"))! {
        print("GIF")
    }
    else {
        print("Unknown")
    }
}
```

Comment: What if user has picked image from camera? For camera input app will crash on " info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL"

Comment: I'm using Swift 5 and had to tweak this slightly. Substitute `info[.imageURL] as! NSURL` for `info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL`

Comment: let assetPath = info[.imageURL] as! NSURL - Swift 4

Comment: if (assetPath.absoluteString?.hasSuffix("jpeg"))! {
            print("jpeg")
        }

Comment: If the user selects the photo from the camera then what should we do?

I tried  ```info[UIImagePickerControllerImageURL] as! NSURL``` but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 4):

You need to cover the image to raw data, probably using `UIImagePNGRepresentation()` or `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()`, then send THAT up to your server. That data will be in either `PNG` or `JPEG` format, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

If preferred using URL, In swift 5.2 you can use

```
enum ImageFormat {
    case png
    case jpeg
    case gif
    case tiff
    case unknown
    
    init(byte: UInt8) {
        switch byte {
        case 0x89:
            self = .png
        case 0xFF:
            self = .jpeg
        case 0x47:
            self = .gif
        case 0x49, 0x4D:
            self = .tiff
        default:
            self = .unknown
        }
    }
}

extension Data {
    var imageFormat: ImageFormat{
        guard let header = map({ $0 as UInt8 })[safe: 0] else {
            return .unknown
        }
        
        return ImageFormat(byte: header)
    }
}

extension Collection {
    
    /// Returns the element at the specified index iff it is within bounds, otherwise nil.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - Parameter index: The index of the item to get safely the element
    /// - Returns: The element if available or nil otherwise
    subscript(safe index: Index) -> Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
    
}
```

I found that:

```
jpegData(compressionQuality: CGFloat)
pngData()
```

Always succeed and it's not memory efficient. In one case I saw an image of 1.6Mb becoming 6MB just because of pngData()

Answer (score 2):

Updated Code:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    guard let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else { return }

    if let assetPath = info[.imageURL] as? URL{
        let URLString = assetPath.absoluteString.lowercased()
        if (URLString.hasSuffix("jpg")) {
            print("JPG")
            uploadedImage = image
            uploadImage(type: ImageTypes.JPG)
        }
        else if (URLString.hasSuffix("jpeg")) {
            print("JPEG")
        }
        else if (URLString.hasSuffix("png")) {
            print("PNG")
        }
        else {
            print("Invalid Type")
        }
    }
    dismiss(animated: true)
}
```